# What is the benefit of automatic variables?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm looking for benefits of "automatic" in Systemverilog.
I have been seeing the "automatic" factorial example. But I can't get though them. Does anyone know why we use "automatic"?

Comment: Kindly ask more specific questions. Automatic variables are like any locally declared variable in C/C++. Normally non-automatic variables in Verilog are like static variables in C/C++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021666/what-is-the-difference-between-automatic-and-static-task-why-we-cant-pass-by-ref/28025207#28025207

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Traditionally, Verilog has been used for modelling hardware at RTL and at Gate level abstractions. Since both RTL and Gate level abstraction are static/fixed (non-dynamic), Verilog supported only static variables. So for example, any **reg** or **wire** in Verilog would be instantiated/mapped at the beginning of simulation and would remain mapped in the simulation memory till the end of simulation. As a result, you can take dump of any wire/reg as a waveform, and the reg/wire would have a value from the beginning till the end, since it is always mapped. In a programmers perspective, such variables are termed **static**. In C/C++ world, to declare such a variable, you will have to use *storage class specifier* **static**. In Verilog every variable is implicitly static.

Note that until the advent of SystemVerilog, Verilog supported only static variables. Even though Verilog also supported some constructs for modelling at behavioural abstraction, the support was limited by absence of **automatic** storage class.

**automatic** (called **auto** in software world) storage class variables are mapped on the stack. When a function is called, all the local (non-static) variables declared in the function are mapped to individual locations in the stack. Since such variables exist only on the stack, they cease to exist as soon as the execution of the function is complete and the stack correspondingly shrinks.

Amongst other advantages, one possibility that this storage class enables is *recursive functions*. In Verilog world, a function can not be re-entrant. Recursive (or re-entrant) functions do not serve any useful purpose in a world where automatic storage class is not available. To understand this, you can imagine a re-entrant function as a function which dynamically makes multiple recursive instantiations of itself. Each instance gets its **automatic** variables mapped on the stack. As we progress into the recursion, the stack grows and each function gets to make its computations using its own set of variables. When the function calls return the computed values are collated and a final result made available. With only static variables, each function call will store the variable values at the same common locations thus erasing any benefit of having multiple calls (instantiations).

Coming to the **factorial** algorithm, it is relatively easy to conceptualize factorial as a recursive algorithm. In maths we write *factorial(n) = n*(factial(n-1))*. So you need to calculate factorial(n-1) in order to know factorial(n). Note that recursion can not be completed without a terminating case, which in case of factorial is n=1.

```
function automatic int factorial;
   input int n;
   if (n > 1)
     factorial = factorial (n - 1) * n;
   else
     factorial = 1;
endfunction
```

Without **automatic** storage class, since all variables in a function would be mapped to a fixed location, when we call factorial(n-1) from inside factorial(n), the recursive call would overwrite any variable inside the caller context. In the factorial function as defined in the above code snippet, if we do not specify the storage class as **automatic**, both **n** and the result **factorial** would be overwritten by the recursive call to factorial(n-1). As a result the variable **n** would consecutively be overwritten as **n-1**, **n-2**, **n-3** and so on till we reach the terminating condition of **n = 1**. The terminating recursive call to factorial would have a value of 1 assigned to **n** and when the recursion unwinds, factorial(n-1) * n would evaluate to 1 in each stage.

With automatic storage class, each recursive function call would have its own place in the memory (actually on the stack) to store variable **n**. As a result consecutive calls to factorial will not overwrite variable **n** of the caller. As a result when the recursion unwinds, we shall have the right value for factorial(n) as n*(n-1)*(n-2)* .. *1.

Note that it is possible to define factorial using iteration as well. And that can be done without use of **automatic** storage class. But in many cases, recursion makes it possible for the user to code algorithms in a more intuitive fashion.

Answer (score 1):

I propose 1 example as below(using *fork...join_none*):

Ex.1 (non-using *automatic*) : value output will be "3 3 3 3". because *i* take the latest value after exit *for* loop, *i* is stored in static memory location. This may be a bug in your code.

```
initial begin   
  for( int i =0; i<=3 ; i++)
    fork
      $write ("%d ", i);
    join_none 
end
```

Ex.2 (using *automatic*) : value output will be "0 1 2 3". Because in each loop, value of *i* is copied to *k*, and fork..join_none spawn a thread with each value of *k* ( each loop will locate 1 memory space for *k : k0, k1, k2, k3*):

```
initial begin   
     for( int i =0; i<=3 ; i++)
        fork
          automatic int k = i;
          $write ("%d ", k);
        join_none 
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example is the use of fork join inside for loop -

Without the use of automatic, the fork join inside the for loop will not work correctly.

```
for (int i=0; i<`SOME_VALUE ; i++) begin
     automatic int id=i;
     fork

      task/function using the id above ;
      ...
     join_none
 end
```